# How to configure OpenSMTPD with Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, opensmtpd

Amazon has instructions for postfix and sendmail, but not [OpenSMTPD](https://www.opensmtpd.org/), so adding them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested with OpenBSD 5.8

1. Verify your domain and a sender in [AWS SES console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home). Save your SMTP Settings.
2. Set up the SMTP authentication details in the mail secrets database (replacing `$smtpUsername:$smtpPassword` with the values from step 1)

   ```
   # touch /etc/mail/secrets
   # chmod 640 /etc/mail/secrets
   # chown root:_smtpd /etc/mail/secrets
   # echo "ses $smtpUsername:$smtpPassword" >> /etc/mail/secrets
   # makemap /etc/mail/secrets
   ```
3. Configure OpenSMTPD:

   ```
   # nano /etc/mail/smtpd.conf

   listen on lo0
   table aliases db:/etc/mail/aliases.db
   table secrets db:/etc/mail/secrets.db
   accept for local alias <aliases> deliver to mbox
   accept from local for any relay via tls+auth://ses@email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com auth <secrets>
   ```
4. Restart OpenSMTPD:

   ```
   # rcctl restart smtpd
   ```
5. Test it:

   ```
   # sendmail -v -f verified-sender@verified-domain.com to@example.com
   Subject: test subject

   test body
   ^D
   ```

Errors?

watch your line-breaks in `smtpd.conf`

`# smtpd -n` to check for syntax errors in `smtpd.conf`

Try port 587 if your machine is blocking port 25 (add :587 to end of aws url in `smtpd.conf`)